# InLine Editing Lightning Styling

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, inline

I'm currently working on a Lightning component that I can include in my object. The main goal is to divide the fields I have created for that object in various tabs. There are too many fields to have them in just one tab. Additionally, I would like to implement some visibility logic for some of the fields.

I was able to figure out the MVC concept by watching this session (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BK-jYea5ogo) but currently I'm stuck at the styling. Is there an example to style the input fields so they look like in the Lightning design (incl. inline editing). I have a screenshot how it should look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9b8q.jpg

I wasn't able to find anything in the Lightning Design Ressource Center.

***Edit:***
I guess the only thing I have to change is to have a different view / style when it's in viewing mode and once I double click it changes into the editing / input field mode.

Answer (score 1):

New for Spring 17:

You can use the [Related Record Component](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_comp_related_record.htm)

Just add it in your app builder, then you can select an "Action" for current record, or for a related object record.

Let's say you want to create that for the Opportunity object. So for displaying specific records from the opportunity, add an "Update a Record" action to the opportunity object, then from the Opportunity record home app builder - add a Related Record Component, and select the Opportunity action that you have just added.

If you want to display account details of this opportunity - create an action for the account, and then from the Opportunity record home app builder - add a Related Record Component, and select the Account action that you have just added.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey while this is definitely helpful it doesn't solve my problem. I want to split up fields from one object throughout multiple tabs. That wouldn't be solved by the new feature.

Comment: Yes it would - you need to create a different action for each set of fields, and then you can add a component for each action into a new tab

Comment: I understand but I want to split the fields from one single object. This relates to including fields from an other object.

Comment: you can show fields also from the current object